# Postfix is not following virtual_alias_maps. All mail routed to one user

Tags: postfix

Postfix 2.5.5 on fc8. Shouldn't the following configuration send mail according to /etc/postfix/virtual? Everything is being delivered to user1. The "to" in the header reads somebody@domain2.com or somebodyelse@domain2.com, but the mail indeed is delivered to user1. /var/log/maillog even shows the redirection. What the problem is?

```
Jun 26 19:42:31 fedora postfix/local[29621]: 5C43A60B74E: to=<user1@domain1.net>, orig_to=<user2@domain2.com>, relay=local, delay=0.3, delays=0.3/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
```

/etc/postfix/virtual:

```
somebody@domain2.com      user3
somebodyelse@dpomain2.com   user2
@domain1.net      user1
```

/etc/postfix/main.cf (several lines omitted, available upon request):

```
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
myhostname = domain1.net
home_mailbox = Maildir/
mailbox_command =
virtual_alias_domains = domain2.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
smtpd_sender_restrictions = hash:/etc/postfix/access 
mydomain = domain1.net
myorigin = $mydomain
```

note: /etc/postfix/access just REJECT's a couple spammy domains.

Answer (score 1):

Its because you have domain1.net in your /etc/postfix/virtual file and yet it is not a virtual domain its in your mydestination domains.Either use it as a destination or add it to virtual_alias_domains.